# Method of Undetermined Coefficients - Correct $Y_p(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hey guys just want to make sure that I'm understanding this correctly:

> $y''-y'+3y=2e^x+3x^2 $
>
> has a $Y_p(x)=Axe^x+Bx^2+Cx+D$
>
> Where we have $Axe^x$ as we have $$Y_c=c_1e^{\frac{1+\sqrt{11}}{2}}+c_2e^{\frac{1-\sqrt{11}}{2}}$$ 
>   or would it just be $Ae^x?$
>   Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would just be $A e^x$ - because the homogeneous solution does **not** have an $e^x$ term.

Comment: @Moo I just realised should $ Y_c = c_1e^{\frac {1+\sqrt{11}}{2}x}+c_2e^{\frac {1-\sqrt{11}}{2}x}$ instead?

Comment: Yes, you forgot the $x$ terms, but correctly added them to your comment.However, that in no way changes my original comment. If those roots for the complementary solution were $\pm~ 1$, then we would have had to choose $A x e^x$. Clear?

Comment: @Moo perfect thank you :)

Comment: I meant if the roots were $+1$, not $\pm ~1$, but I think you got it.